# How to stub an XML file in rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, stub

I need to create this fake XML file that will be used to test my model, that reads XML files and manipulate them. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: dont stub, use a fixture file

Comment: The problem is that the real file is grabbed from an URL, so I still need to create a way to simulate this file

Comment: then use vcr: https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Answer (score 0):

As apneadiving said:
then use vcr: http://github.com/vcr/vcr